# Greybox Overlay Changes Size of Window

Tags: css, ajax, scrollbar, overlay, greybox

I am using greybox on my business site so that users can login and access their accounts.
[Example of my site](http://develop.f12media.com)

When the window is activated by selecting "login" or "sign up" at the top of the page, the size of the page or window either expands or changes (discovered by showing scroll bars on bottom and right of window.) How can I keep this from happening? I want the page to have the same size as it did before the window was activated.

Comment: In FireFox it has scroll bars before you press login.

Comment: I was using Google Chrome and Internet Explorer when the incident occurred. You think the issue is the original page and not the pop up window?

Comment: To clarify the issue is scroll box on the bottom (left and right scroll) I understand that the page should have an up and down scroll

Comment: i don't think we can hidden the horizontal scrollbar, but to hidden the vertical scrollbar you just need set id="GB_overlay" width to 100%. i think it's better to use position fixed for the pop up window, so if we scroll the page, the pop up will stay in place.

Comment: I downloaded Firefox's browser and tested the webpage. I found that I do not have the issue in firefox, but the issue does occur in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.

Comment: I don't get the issue in Chrome.

Comment: tried to reproduce the error in chrome, safari, and firefox and can't :-/

Comment: Yoel Fixed the issue by suggesting "fixed" on the GB_overlay rule. That corrected the problem and it shows correctly for all browsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yoel's solution worked. He suggested changing the style sheet to reflect "fixed" with 100% width. This fixed the issue on all browsers.

Comment: -1, It would have been nice to tell him to post it as an answer and accept that to give him the credit and some rep.

Comment: How do I tell him this other than posting that in the comments? I have and he did not respond.

Comment: Correct, you can only post it among the comments. Something along the lines of this maybe: "Hi Yoel, your solution worked. I see you're a new user as well, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.". Then you could have waited more than 2 days, some of us are less fanatics than most.

Answer (score 0):

While an old thread, for those still using greybox, the following update might be helpful:

Setting the GB_overlay position to "fixed" (in gb_styles.css) as Yoel suggested solved the problem for greyboxes that are not full screen (e.g., gb_page_center), but a full screen greybox (e.g., GB_showPage) still had the horizontal scrollbar and expanding browser window on Chrome, Edge, Chrome on iOS, and Safari on iOS.

Setting the GB_overlay width to 100% wasn't needed for the non-full screen greyboxes, and didn't fix the problem for a full screen greybox. Instead, setting the GB_overlay *max-width* to 100% fully resolved the expanding browser and horizontal scroll bar appearance in Chrome, Edge, Chrome on iOS, and Safari on iOS.

As Kevin also experienced, Firefox never had these problems with greybox, and these updated changes to the GB_overlay css had no effect on Firefox;s always correct rendering of the greybox.